# ACTION_TIME_CHANGED Broadcast called for every single minute

Tags: android, datetime, broadcast

on API 19 and in between API 23 every single minute Broadcast is fired. My Intent filter for the broadcast only have android.intent.action.TIME_SET filter and its registered on runtime.

This issue is not observed on all devices running on the above platform. Only few set of devices.

Is this a known AOSP bug or is there any workaround with it?

My Requirement is to Call the broadcast whenever User manually change the time and auto update is turned off for Date & Time

Answer (score 0):

True , I have same problem but it wasn't working in Samsung and works well with other phones, and actually I solved that by not depending on that Broadcast doing AlarmManager  and sending Broadcast from it , something like that and you can do it in a background service with yourService.startAlarm()

```
          public void startAlarm()
        {
     Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
     calendar.add(Calendar.MILLISECOND, INTERVAL_MILLIS);
     Log.e("AlarmWidget","Started");
     Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(AqiWidgetProvider.ACTION_AUTO_UPDATE);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(mContext, ALARM_ID,         alarmIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    // RTC does not wake the device up
    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), INTERVAL_MILLIS, pendingIntent);

}


    public void stopAlarm()
{
    Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(AqiWidgetProvider.ACTION_AUTO_UPDATE);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(mContext, ALARM_ID,     alarmIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
}
```

Comment: How does it solve the problem? You are creating an alarm manager. My requirement is to call the broadcast when ever user manually change the Date and Time.

Comment: yeah I created Alarm Manager to send broadcast depend on (INTERVAL_MILLIS) you set  and receiving the broadcast exactly the same time, so i depended on My Broadcast not the system one as it's sometimes not getting it, and in the class which extends the BroadCastReceiver you could check on it.